# Wrong gcc behaviour with lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda

By compiling this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string makeList (std::string sep)
{
    auto makeItem = [&] (std::string item)
    {
        static char count = '0';
        return (++count, count) + sep + item + '\n';
    };

    return makeItem ("first") + makeItem ("second") + makeItem ("third");
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << makeList (". ");
}
```

with gcc (5.4.0, c++11 flag) the output is this:

```
3. first
2. second
1. third
```

while the correct output, which clang (3.8, c++11 flag) gets, is:

```
1. first
2. second
3. third
```

Is there a particular reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Order of evaluation of subexpressions is unspecified, meaning your compiler can choose to execute those `makeItem` calls in any order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.

There is no right or wrong here, GCC evaluates right-to-left and clang left-to-right